# AS3. Animated pop-up window in Flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, animation, popup

I'm creating flash game and for now I have simple menu, when clicking button close current window and add new one.

Maybe could you suggest any script for animated pop-up new window or custom menu? Thank you.

For now I use simple this:

```
btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);

private function start(event:Event):void
{
    menu_background.visible = false;
    removeChild(btn_play);
    removeChild(btn_control);
    removeChild(btn_credits);
    removeChild(btn_quit);
    addChild(secondBackground);
    addChild(btn_back);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lots of Tweens for the pop-up by [GreenSock](http://www.greensock.com/category/actionscript/).

For example:

```
//Fade in and Fade out
TweenLite.to([menu_background, btn_play, btn_control, btn_credits, btn_quit], 0.5, {alpha:0, onComplete:function()
{
    menu_background.visible = false;
    removeChild(btn_play);
    removeChild(btn_control);
    removeChild(btn_credits);
    removeChild(btn_quit);
    addChild(secondBackground);
    addChild(btn_back);
    //Immediately set the alpha of secondBackground and btn_back to 0 and tween them to alpha 1 in 0.5 second
    TweenLite.from( [secondBackground, btn_back], 0.5, {alpha:0} );
}});
```

Experiment more with the [TweenLite/Max Plugin Explorer](http://www.greensock.com/as/swf/PluginExplorer-v11.swf).